What is the relation between $A$ and $e^A$ for unbounded self-adjoint $A$?
Is there a generally accepted definition of the exponential of certain unbounded operators on a Hilbert space, which extends that for self-adjoint operators given by the functional calculus?  I would like for it to apply also to self-adjoint operators which are not bounded above.
Specifically, if $A = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda \,dE$ is a self-adjoint operator, we can take its exponential $e^A = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^\lambda \,dE$ using the measurable functional calculus.  When $A$ is bounded above, the exponential $e^A$ is a bounded operator.  In this case $A$ is the generator of the $C_0$ semigroup $e^{tA}$.  Hence the exponential of a self-adjoint operator bounded above is characterized by a general condition applicable to non-normal generators of $C_0$ semigroups, namely that if $A$ generates the $C_0$ semigroup $T^t$, then $e^A = T^1$.
My question is the following.  When $A$ is self-adjoint but not bounded above, we can still form the unbounded densely defined exponential $e^A$ through the functional calculus.  Is there in this case a general characterization of $e^A$ which would apply also to non-normal $A$?
A naive attempt would be that there is an increasing sequence of projections $P_n$ which tend strongly to the identity, with ranges which reduce both $A$ and $e^A$, and such that $AP_n$ generates a $C_0$ semigroup $T_n^t$ on the range of $P_n$ with $T_n^1 = e^AP_n$.  (In the self-adjoint case we can take $P_n = E(\lambda<n)$.)  In other words $e^{tA}$ and $A$ are injective limits of $C_0$ semigroups and their generators.  A more sophisticated approach is given by Hughes in the context of Banach spaces.

Let $E$ be the spectral measure for $A$. Then $e^Ax$ is defined for all vectors $x$ for which
$$
   \|e^{A}x\|^2=\left\| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\lambda}dE(\lambda)x \right\|^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\lambda}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty.
$$
$e^{A}x$ is defined by
$$
         e^{A}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\lambda}dE(\lambda)x.
$$
The domain $\mathcal{D}(e^{A})$ consists of all $x$ for which
$$
             \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\lambda}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty.
$$
The operator $e^{A} : \mathcal{D}(e^{A}) \rightarrow X$ is closed and densely-defined.

Thank you, but I am looking for a notion of exponential that encompasses both that for unbounded normal operators which you give here and that for (non-normal) generators of strongly continuous semigroups.
